# Some misunderstanding using Array#map method

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have following block of code:

```
arr = ['a','b','c']
arr.map {|item| item <<'1'} #=> ['a1','b1','c1']
arr #=> ['a1','b1','c1']
```

Why does `Array#map` change the array? It should only create a new one. When I'm using `+` in the block instead of `<<`, it works as expected. Does `Array#each` change the array itself, or does it only iterate over it and return itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: Why does `map` change array? it should only create new.

`map` doesn't change the `Array`. But `<<` changes the `String`s in the `Array`.

See [the documentation for `String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3C):

> ```
> str << obj → str
> ```
>
> Append—Concatenates the given object to `str`.

Although it isn't mentioned explicitly, the code example clearly shows that `<<` mutates its receiver:

```
a = "hello "
a << "world"   #=> "hello world"
a.concat(33)   #=> "hello world!"
```

> It's strange, because when I'm using `+` operator in the block insted of `<<` it works as expected.

`+` doesn't change the `String`s in the `Array`.

See [the documentation for `String#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-2B):

> ```
> str + other_str → new_str
> ```
>
> Concatenation—Returns a new `String` containing `other_str` concatenated to `str`.

Note how it says "new `String`" and also the return value is given as `new_str`.

> And my second question: Does `Array#each` change array itself or it only iterate over array and return itself?

`Array#each` does not change the `Array`. But of course, the *block* passed to `Array#each` may or may not change individual *elements* of the `Array`:

```
arr = %w[a b c]
arr.map(&:object_id)          #=> an array of three large numbers
arr.each {|item| item <<'1' } #=> ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
arr.map(&:object_id)          #=> an array of the same three large numbers
```

As you can see, `Array#each` did not change the `Array`: it is still the same `Array` with the same three elements.

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` or `each` makes difference on the outer array (`map` will return a new array, `each` will return the original array), but it will not make difference on what strings the array contains; in either case, the strings contained in the array will be the original strings modified.